# Delete entity in OneToMany relationship keeping other side entity (JPA)

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I know the title is not so clear but it's the best title I could come up with. Let me explain it better.
I have a web app written in Java using Spring as a backend framework and I'm using JPA to handle the MySql database.
Let's say we have these two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Item{
   private Long itemId;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="item")
   private List<Purchase> purchases;
   ...
}

@Entity
public class Purchase{
   private Long purchaseId;
   @ManyToOne
   private Item item;
}
```

I would like to keep the purchases even if the related item would get deleted by the owner.
If I delete the item,

```
itemRepository.delete(item);
```

what would happen to the purchases associated with it? 
Does it depend with the cascade property of the OneToMany annotation?

Comment: Yes. If you have a cascade DELETE, the purchases will be deleted. If not, then you'll have an exception, because you'll have a foreign key constraint violation in your database (it would reference an entity that you're trying to delete). Why don't you try it and see by yourself?

Comment: Yes the point is that I would like to know which is the recommended way to do that. I mean, if I delete Item I would always have that exception you are talking about. What should I do to handle it? Should I try catch it every time or is there an alternative in order to maybe just have a null value instead of the item object?

Comment: Well, what would you like the purchases to become? Either they disappear too, or they stay, but can't reference an item that doesn't exist anymore. So, if you want the latter, set the purchases item to null before deleting the item.

Comment: Yes I would prefer the latter. So what you suggest is to manually set all its purchases to null before deleting it? Thank you very much @JBNizet

Comment: Isn't it a problem to have a foreign key set to null? Does it accept it anyway?

Comment: If the column is nullable, yes, of course. The foreign key constraint only apples if the column has a value. Not if it's null.

Comment: @StefanoSambruna Also, it would have been a nice idea to take a look at your foreign key and make sure that it's not declared as `ON UPDATE CASCADE` because that would mean that each time you delete a "parent" row in the items table all "children" rows in the purchase table having that particular item_id as foreign key would have been also deleted.

Comment: @StefanoSambruna Correction about my comment, I meant `ON DELETE CASCADE`